# std::launder и strict aliasing

Tags: c++, stl, strict-aliasing

Вообщем у меня в голове возникла небольшая путаница с **strict aliasing** и **std::launder**. По стандарту следующий код является UB:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(&x);
    *p = 1.0f;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Но будет ли UB если использовать **std::launder**?

```
void foo(int x)
{
    float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(&x);
    *p = 1.0f;
    std::cout << *std::launder(&x) << std::endl;
}
```

Фактически, на современных версиях компиляторов *(по крайней мере у меня)* обе версии кода отработают правильно, но первая это гарантированно UB, а со второй у меня возникли сложности с пониманием.

На многих форумах (и в некоторых статьях) второй код приводится как пример работы **std::launder**, но разве это все еще не UB по формальным причинам?

Comment: Обе версии вызывают UB. Оно происходит из-за разыменования указателя `p` в этой строке: `*p = 1.0f;`. Наличие `std::launder` ничего не меняет. Также потенциально могут быть проблемы при приведении указателя `int*` к `float*` из-за нарушения требований по выравниванию, но обычно у типов `int` и `float` одинаковые требования по выравниванию и такое приведение безопасно.

Comment: @wololo правильно ли я понимаю, что если разыменовывать указатель `p` через `std::launder` UB также будет происходить?

Comment: Да, всё верно. [Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/MPPa7xP5z).

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @mazik7512, а вы понимаете в каких случаях может проявиться данное "UB"?

Comment: @avp если сработают оптимизации компилятора, называемые **strict aliasing**.

Comment: @mazik7512, на самом деле здесь  кроме strict aliasing-а (с которым несложно бороться) UB тут состоит в том, что на некоторых (сейчас совсем не распростаненных архитектурах) не все значения int являются допустимыми для float, что может вызвать exception там.  Вы в самом деле рассчитываете писать нетленку для всего зоопарка?

Comment: @avp вообще вопрос был про то что в виде объяснения работы `std::launder` на многих сайтах приводится подобный кусок кода *(из вопроса)*, а не про допустимость значений **int** для **float** (что явно намного менее распространенная ошибка).

Comment: @mazik7512, всегда считал, что расширить чьи-то познания это хорошо...

Comment: @avp так-то оно конечно так, но какое-то это очень слабое расширение, что где-то там, на каких-то там архитектурах, какие-то значения являются непригодными.

Comment: @mazik7512, это о том, что очень многие UB (но не ) на практике являются скорее надуманными (по  крайней мере машинозависимыми).  (кстати, взял и прямо сейчас посмотрел -- у меня в `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` на  AMD Ryzen 5 3400G  strict aliasing в вашем примере не наблюдается) (и о чем это говорит по вашему?)

Comment: А разве UB буквально это и не означает *(зависимость от реализации/архитектуры)*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::launder` не для этого (тут он не убирает UB).

Он нужен когда указатель на правильный тип, но сам указатель был получен нелегальным путем.

Самый популярный пример:

```
alignas(MyClass) char buffer[sizeof(MyClass)];

::new((void *)buffer) MyClass;
```

Вот если теперь сделать `reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(buffer)` - то результат нужно обработать `std::launder`, иначе будет UB.

А если сохранить возвращаемое значение `new` - указатель можно использовать как есть.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а то на многих сайтах, пример из вопроса приводится как объяснение работы `std::launder`.